# How to properly do a server side api request?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am very new with node js and decided to learn how to secure api keys, i've looked everywhere but can't find a example. But i found some that suggest the only way is to do a server side api request.

I am using openweathermap api for this code, i get the expected data back as a response in chrome network tab but i have questions regarding it.

1. How do i use the response data (e.g getting the current weather, temp) ?
2. Is this the proper way on doing a server side api request in node.js?

```js
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    if (req.url === '/') {
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/index.html').pipe(res);
    } else if (req.url === '/getweather') {
        var weatherApiURL = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=<API KEY>';
        request(weatherApiURL, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                res.writeHead(500, 'Weather API request failed', {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
                res.end();
            } else {
                res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'application/json'});
                res.end(body);
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.end('not found')
    }
}).listen(8080);
```

Front:

```js
function requestWeatherData() { 
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', '/getweather', true); 
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
    xhr.onload = function () { 
        console.log(this.responseText); 
    }; 
    xhr.send(); 
};
```

Thank you in advanced!!

Comment: instead of res.end(body);  use res.json(body); and remove thisres.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'application/json'});

Comment: Is that for express? i am not using express

Comment: Are you using the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module? or is that a custom request function?

Comment: oh yes i am using the request module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Part 1: How to use the data.

The first thing you'll want to do is to check whether the request succeeded

```
if (this.status !== 200) {
    // The request did not work.
    throw new Error('Cannot use data.');
}
```

Once the requset status has been verified you need to 'parse' the response.

```
const weatherData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

// Lets see the js object:
console.log(weatherData);
```

Now you can do whatever you need with the data.

The full example:

```
function requestWeatherData() { 
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', '/getweather', true); 
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
    xhr.onload = function () { 
        if (this.status !== 200) {
            // The request did not work.
            throw new Error('Cannot use data.');
        }

        const weatherData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

        // Lets see the js object:
        console.log(weatherData);
    }; 
    xhr.send(); 
};
```

### Part 2: Is there a proper way of doing this?

Now, I don't not know enough about this to say definitely, however, here are some concerns that you may want to think about.

1. Most APIs have rate limits, meaning you probably want to try to 'cache' the requests somewhere to reduce the need to 'poll' the APIs
2. Other people could use your exposed url in their application.
3. Writing all of the routes as you are currently will become a real headache for larger applications, I can recommend express from experience for small to medium applications.

Comment: Late response.. how would i secure the exposed url ? and thank you this is very helpful

Comment: How exactly can they use the url ? i tried to use the url on different app and i got `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'`  error

Comment: The second observation is purely from a server side point of view, anyone with knowledge or your API can just use that instead of the Open Weather API.

Comment: With regards to how you would go about trying to secure your endpoint, you could use the '[Authorization Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization)' or a similar technique to verify the user is allowed to make the request